# jQuery checked checkboxes sibling text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to return a string of label text from the following html if the checkbox is ticked:

```
<ul id="mainList" class="checkboxlist">
    <li class="checkboxlist-item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Categories_0" value="ff2db3bf-479e-4b3a-a2e4-a27d00bbc038" name="Categories.SelectedIds"  />
        <label for="Categories_0">Arts/Culture</label>
    </li>
    <li class="checkboxlist-item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Categories_1" value="0a46de03-84f7-4a66-abe9-a22200cc6dc4" name="Categories.SelectedIds"  />
        <label for="Categories_1">Beauty</label>
    </li>
    <li class="checkboxlist-item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Categories_2" value="cf4fc161-a195-4e3e-9262-a22200cc5650" name="Categories.SelectedIds"  />
        <label for="Categories_2">Business</label>
    </li>
    <li class="checkboxlist-item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Categories_3" value="a119f0a9-2cf6-4c7c-a25c-a29001179f64" name="Categories.SelectedIds"  />
        <label for="Categories_3">Car/Motoring</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It's important to use #mainList, and then return the label text if the input type checkbox is true.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use .map() to get an array of text

```
var array = $('#mainList input:checked').next().map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

- `#mainList input:checked` get set of checked input elements under `#mainList`
- [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) get the next elements of each element in the set - the `label` in this case
- [.map(...)](http://api.jquery.com/map/)[.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) convert the set of elements to an array

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#mainList input').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
      alert($(this).next('label').text())
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a2F3j/1/)